# Converting latitude & longitude to x & y Mollweide map coordinates using a Newton-Raphson iteration in Python

Tags: python, math, maps, astronomy

I'm trying to write a program that will take a set of longitude & latitude coordinates from the user, convert them to x & y coordinates for a Mollweide projection map, and then report the value of the pixel at those coordinates (in this case, a noise temperature).

The map/data I'm using is the [Haslam 408 MHz All Sky Survey](https://lambda.gsfc.nasa.gov/product/foreground/fg_haslam_get.cfm) which is provided as a Mollweide projection map. This data is in .fits format and is a large all-sky survey of noise in the 408 MHz band.

According to the [Mollweide projection Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide_projection), it is possible to use a Newton-Raphson iteration to convert from longitude/latitude to x/y map coordinates. I based the iteration scheme in my program largely on the methods from the Wikipedia page and in [this GitHub post](https://gist.github.com/zeimusu/9fcf649171c72c6a5ac5).

However, my program does not appear to be reporting the correct values for the longitude and latitude that I'm inputting. I largely suspect that one of two (or both) factors are contributing to this error:

1. The way that I'm implementing the iteration scheme is incorrect, and thus resulting in incorrect values being reported.
2. I don't properly understand what the radius value, R, represents in the iteration scheme. I can't find any literature on how to determine the proper R value beyond that "R is the radius of the globe to be projected." I assumed that this would be based upon the size of the map in pixels; in this case, the map image is 4096x2048 pixels, so I've tried using 2048, 1024, and simply 1 as the R values, to no avail.

Below I have provided my code for review:

```
from math import sin, cos, pi, sqrt, asin
from astropy.io import fits

hdulist = fits.open('data.fits')
hdulist.info()
data = hdulist[1].data

sqrt2 = sqrt(2)

def solveNR(lat, epsilon=1e-6): #this solves the Newton Raphson iteration
    if abs(lat) == pi / 2:
        return lat  # avoid division by zero
    theta = lat
    while True:
        nexttheta = theta - (
            (2 * theta + sin(2 * theta) - pi * sin(lat)) /
            (2 + 2 * cos(2 * theta))
        )
        if abs(theta - nexttheta) < epsilon:
            break
        theta = nexttheta
    return nexttheta


def checktheta(theta, lat): #this function is also currently unused while debugging
    return (2 * theta + sin(2 * theta), pi * sin(lat))


def mollweide(lat, lon, lon_0=0, R=1024):
    lat = lat * pi / 180
    lon = lon * pi / 180
    lon_0 = lon_0 * pi / 180  # convert to radians
    theta = solveNR(lat)
    return (R * 2 * sqrt2 * (lon - lon_0) * cos(theta) / pi,
            R * sqrt2 * sin(theta))


def inv_mollweide(x, y, lon_0=0, R=1024, degrees=True): # inverse procedure (x, y to lat, long). Currently unused

    theta = asin(y / (R * sqrt2))
    if degrees:
        factor = 180 / pi
    else:
        factor = 1
    return (
        asin((2 * theta + sin(2 * theta)) / pi) * factor,
        (lon_0 + pi * x / (2 * R * sqrt(2) * cos(theta))) * factor
    )
def retrieve_temp(lat, long): #retrieves the noise temp from the data file after calling the mollweide function
    lat = int(round(lat))
    long = int(round(long))
    coords = mollweide(lat, long)
    x, y= coords
    x = int(round(x))
    y= int(round(y))
    x = x-1
    y = y-1
    if x < 0:
        x = x*(-1)
    if y < 0:
        y = y*(-1)
    print("The noise temperature is: ",data[y, x],"K")

def prompt(): #this is the terminal UI
    cont = 1
    while cont == 1:
        lat_cont = 1
        while lat_cont == 1:
            lat = float(input('Please enter the latitude: '))
            lat_val = 1
            while lat_val == 1:
                if lat > 180 or lat < -180:
                    lat = float(input('Invalid input. Make sure your latitude value is in range -180 to 180 degrees \n'
                            'Please enter the latitude: '))
                else:
                    lat_val = 0
                    lat_cont = 0
        long_cont = 1
        while long_cont == 1:
            long = float(input('Please enter the longitude: '))
            long_val = 1
            while long_val == 1:
                if long > 90 or long < -90:
                    long = float(input('Invalid input. Make sure your latitude value is in range -90 to 90 degrees \n'
                            'Please enter the latitude: '))
                else:
                    long_val = 0
                    long_cont = 0
        retrieve_temp(lat, long)
        valid = 1
        while valid == 1:
            ans = input('Would you like to continue? Y or N: ').lower()
            ans_val = 1
            while ans_val ==1:
                if not (ans == 'y' or ans == 'n'):
                    ans = input('Invalid input. Please answer Y or N to continue or exit: ')
                elif ans == 'y':
                    ans_val = 0
                    cont = 1
                    valid = 0
                elif ans == 'n':
                    ans_val = 0
                    cont = 0
                    valid = 0

prompt()
hdulist.close()
```

Apologies if I failed to follow typical Python conventions in the above code; I'm new to Python.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're doing this as a personal project, and don't want to use any existing toolkits, in particular something like proj4?

Comment: @barrycarter Yes, I'm an undergraduate Astro student doing this as a personal summer project to keep my coding skills sharp with something Astro related.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks reasonable. My advice about figuring out what's wrong:

(1) Try evaluating your `mollweide` and `inv_mollweide` functions at points for which you know what the results are supposed to be. E.g. points on the equator or prime meridian or something easy like that.

(2) Are your `mollweide` and `inv_mollweide` actually inverses? i.e. if you take your output from the one and put it into the other, you should get the original input back again.

(3) How do results change as you move around on the map? Do you get correct results in some areas (e.g. near middle of map) and not others? What happens as you get nearer to the edges? Does it gradually become more inaccurate or is there some threshold, beyond which you get grossly incorrect answers?

I think a feature of Newton's method is that it converges only if you're close enough to a solution to begin with, otherwise you can get anything. I don't know how close you have to be, for this problem.

This seems like a great problem. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! To answer (3), part of the reason I know that this method isn't working properly is that certain (valid) long/lat inputs return a value (noise temp) of 0.00, which shouldn't be possible unless the x-y pair was outside of what is considered the map. I'll be looking into making sure that I'm close enough to a solution to get an answer that makes sense.

Comment: OK. My advice is to verify that the coordinate conversion before looking at the output (the noise temp value).

Answer (score 0):

so this is going to sound really strange, but as far as I know there aren't actually any good Python libraries for Mollweide conversions, at least for Mollweide maps that span the entire earth. The EPSG system is bizarrely incomplete, which makes Pyproj more or less unusable for this purpose. I plan on using your code as part of a project of my own, but if you'd like to setup a github library and maybe even some kind of pip functionality (I'm fairly new to Python myself, so I'm really not who to ask on how to do that), I'm happy to give you credit.